# Что происходит с медиа-контентом при отправке email письма?

Tags: email, email-layout

**Задача**: создать и отправить письмо, в которое нужно добавить изображение, загруженное через форму.

**Вопрос**: при отправке письма изображение отправляется в теле или догружается из внешнего источника?

Answer (score 1):

Я советую прочитать алгоритм передачи данных через tcp/ip.
При передаче, файл делится на пакеты и отправляется получателю. Ваш файл копируется и пока не будет получен отчёт о успешной передаче, копия не удалится. Копию естественно Вы не увидите. Это все делается внутри стека протокола. 
А письмо написанное Вами, это только для Вас.

Answer (score 0):

Файл разбивается на пакеты и уходят по tcp

Comment: Ну то есть, нет необходимости хранить файл после того как письмо отправлено, я правильно понял?